# add running list of dates to sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is the result of a query. 
It is a calendar in essence. 
I want to set the start date and for the date field to be populated with a running list of Dates as in the below example. starting with a date I declare (In the example this is set as 2017-04-29)
Order is the order in which the Item is to be made. 
Days is the number of days that item has been worked on (first day returns 1, second day: 2, and so on). 
It is currently ordered by 'order' column then 'days' column

Current Output

```
Date        Item    Order   Days
Null        WP-1    1       1
Null        SP1     2       1
Null        SP1     2       2
Null        WP-2    3       1
```

Desired Output

```
Date        Item    Order   Days
2017-04-29  WP-1    1       1
2017-04-30  SP1     2       1
2017-05-01  SP1     2       2
2017-05-02  WP-2    3       1
```

I do have 'numbers' and 'dates' tables if they help

This is for SQL Server 2008

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number` and add it to the specified start date.

```
declare @startdate date;
set @startdate = '2017-04-29';
select dateadd(day, row_number() over(order by [order],days)-1, @startdate) as [date],
item,[order],days
from yourtable
```

Comment: This is perfect. I did have an idea the row_number would be involved, but couldn't think of how to write it. Understand this perfectly so thanks!